# Gradle build finished with 1 error(s)

Tags: android-studio

[error getting while running project in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcZmM.png)

I already tried to solve my problem by changing sdk

Comment: What was the error? You can't expect to get help without giving your code, stack trace.

Comment: I can not post screen shot actually I am getting this error  ** "Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 14s 157ms"**

Comment: @kika Then we cannot help you. Please post stack trace or screen shot of the error.

Comment: Same here.Long list of [DEBUG] output with not a single [ERROR] or [WARNING] and the finishing line "Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) "

Answer (score 0):

u can clear gradle,have a try.do u hava a screenshot for me